# How to find a ModalPopupExtender in a JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages, modalpopupextender

I need to write a Javascript function that run from Master page, to find a ModalPopup in the contenct page and close it. Following code works, but not what I want. I need use something like mpeEditUser.ClientID, but I got an error. Also, it would be nice if I could find a ModalPopup without knowing its id, by its type (ModalPopupExtender) instead. Any suggestion?

```
 function CloseModalPopup() {
        var mpu = $find('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mpeEditUser');
        mpu.hide();

    }
```

Here is my solution: (If you see any problem, please let me know. Thanks)
I get the ModalPopup id in the codebehind, and pass it to my javascript function.

In the Page_Load of the default.master.cs:

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
string sMpeID = (AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender)cph.FindControl("mpeEditUser");
```

In my Javascript function:

```
var mpe = $find('<%=sMpeID%>');
if (mpe != null) {
            mpe.hide();
}
```

Comment: "*...but I got an error.*" - how interesting.  Care to share what the error was?  =)

Comment: Sorry. I updated my question. Basically i got an erro CS0103: The name 'mpeEditUser' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

Its likely the tag is getting mucked up by being called through another page, this happened to me. I don't know the best fix for you, however the way I addressed the issue was to first find the mpe through a javascript function that looked for a vague match out of all of the elements on the page.

```
var elemets = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var mpe;
for (var i = 0; i < elemets.length; i++) {
    var id = elemets[i].id
    if (id.indexOf("mpe") >= 0) {
        mpe = elemets[i];
    }
}
```

If you have more then one mpe on the page you may want to match more if the string. For me the elements function only returned about 50 elements, so it was not too much overhead. That may not be the case for you, but even if you dont use this function in the final product it will assist you in discovering the actual ID of the elment.